# Positioning news in IE7 (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-float

Somehow my news is pushed down in Internet Explorer 7 (on all other browsers its ok).
I want to get rid of the gap between the menu's and the news, so the news will fit to the menu area's.

Any idea where I can find the missing link?

Website is: http://www.e107webdesign.nl

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you could post an example of your problem then we might be able to provide assistance.

Comment: So sorry, forgot the link: http://www.e107webdesign.nl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler way of solving this. Just change the source order and wrap divs around the ones on the left side, and ones on the right.

http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/57

Otherwise it will be a PITA to solve this. I hope you are able to modify this somewhat easily and are not constrained by e107 ( horrible CMS imo ).

If source order does matter, you'll probably have to rely on a negative margin + float technique.

PS: For the love of god use `-moz-border-radius/-webkit-border-radius/border-radius` and DD_roundies script instead of wrapping 90000 divs for rounded corners.

Comment: My code worked fine in Firefox/Chrome/IE7 before you recently made edits which consisted of changing `relative` to `absolute` and such. If you want to see how it was, revert your css to the way it was.

Comment: Hi Meder, I still have the old css, just trying some things out. thanks for helping.